# Combining two dataframes with different time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I am doing a study in school about the effect of noise in a person's environment and his/her activity.

I have two dataframes with data I would like to compare. The data was recorded at the same time, but the time intervals between measurements are different. This makes it hard for me to overlay a plot and look at possible correlations.

The data frames look like this:

Volume level:

[image: image volume level df]

steps:

[image: image steps df]

When I try to put these two dataframes in one plot with a sync timeline, the steps graph looks way smaller than the volume level graph. I have tried to plot the two graphs in multiple ways, but I keep ending up with something like this:

[image: The plot I end up with]

Comment: Don't you need to combine the date and time into a combined timestamp?

Comment: instead of images, please include the data inline as text, and also add the code that you have tried thus far

Comment: Riley, do you mean get steps and volume level in one df indexed by time? that would be great but I don't know how.

Comment: Naveed, I am sorry, I know others do it differently, I was in a hurry and I cannot find out how to add dataframes as code

Answer (score 0):

How about this.
This code uses multi y axis so it will help you with your problem that the graph size doesn't fit.

```py
ax = steps_Niels_1st["steps"].plot()
ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax = volume_data_Niels_1st['size'].plot(ax=ax1)
plt.show()
```